# connected components of the fixed point subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, group-actions

Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety with an action of a finite group $G$.
The fixed point subvariety $X^G$ is smooth but may have many connected components.
What determines these connected components geometrically? For example it seems possible to argue that the induced action of $G$ on the tangent spaces of various points on any connected component are all isomorphic as $G$ representations. Does this determine the connected components? More precisely suppose $x,y \in X^G$ and suppose $T_x X \simeq T_yX$ as $G$-representations, then do they lie in the same connected component of $X^G$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $X=\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$ with the $\mathbb{Z_{k}}$-action generated by the map $$\mu. ([x_0:x_1],[y_0:y_1]) =  ([\mu x_0:x_1],[\mu y_0:y_1]),$$ for $\mu = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}$.

Then there are exactly four fixed points $p_0=([1:0],[1:0])$,$p_1=([0:1],[1:0])$,$p_2=([1:0],[0:1])$,$p_3=([0:1],[0:1])$.

The $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$-representations on $T_{p_{1}}(X)$ and $T_{p_{2}}(X)$ are isomorphic. Both are the representation on $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ $\mu.(z_1,z_{2}) = (\mu z_1, \mu^{-1} z_{2})$ in suitable complex coordinates (just choose suitable affine co-ordinates on the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ factors).

Edit:

For the general question, there is one cautionary example that one should be aware of. Consider the $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$-actionon $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $$\mu. [z_0: \ldots :z_{n}] = [\mu z_0: \ldots : z_n].$$ The fixed point set consists of the hyperplane $H = \{z_0=0\} \cong \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ and $p= [1:0: \ldots :0]$.

Next, if $Y \subset H$ is any smooth projective subvariety. Then, one can blow-up $Y$ $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$-equivariantly, since it contained in the fixed point set of the original action. Then, we have a $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$-action on $Bl_{Y}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ for which the fixed set consists of, a point, a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ and a copy of $Y$.

This is quite cautionary, becuase $Bl_{Y}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ is has several geometrically rare properties, for example it is rational. But, $Y$ can be taken to be any smooth projecitve variety, hence there isn't really any geometric properties that carry over to all of the fixed components. Although, in the case that the group action extends to a algebraic group action, there are results that say that *some* of the fixed components inherit geometric properties of $X$, see papers of Bialynicki-Birula and others.

Comment: Ah, nice , thanks ! at the risk of being very imprecise , but is there a way to geometrically understand the  connected components? For example can one characterise actions where the connected components precisely are determined by the induced action on the tangent spaces?

Comment: For algebraic group actions there is a vast literature on this, particular for algebraic torus. But for finite group actions one can say less, there are certain results such as the holomorphic Lefshetz formula.

Comment: There are some examples to be aware of, there are $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$-actions on smooth Fano $3$-folds, for which there is  fixed point component  a smooth curve of genus $1$, so in general the fixed points won't have the same Kodaira dimension as the variety being acted on. (Although for algebraic torus actions there will be at least one fixed component which has the same Kodaira dimension as the variety being acted on, a theorem of Byalinickiu-Birula)

Comment: Thank you Nick , all what you have commented is new to me.

Comment: No problem, regarding " For example can one characterise actions where the connected components precisely are determined by the induced action on the tangent spaces?" I don't think there will be such a nice answer, although it is certainly the case that generically the representations will be different at all the components, I personally don't know of any methods that would allow one to classify the case when there are components with the same representations.